# Why are there no forms in the Visual Style Guide of Web Starter Kit?

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

The Visual Style Guide of the Web Starter Kit provides a couple of elements as reference for your own development. However, I wonder why no forms are provided. In contrast, Bootstrap offers [handy form helpers](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms). Why is there no such thing for Web Starter Kit.

Note, I have found these two guides:

- [Forms and User Input](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/input/)
- Create Amazing Forms

But where is the tl;dr copy paste solution?

Comment: copy and paste from bootstrap and change your css to your needs if you really want some cp.

Comment: Although it's from Web Fundamentals and not WSK, this may be useful: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/input/forms/

Answer (score 0):

In the next version of Web Starter Kit we are hoping to add some things around this:

- Form elements from the material design spec.
- Change the styleguide to have some example forms.

This should be out late january with any bit of luck. You can see the work on the material-sprint branch if you are super keen: https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit/tree/material-sprint

Answer (score 0):

At this date, Web Starter Kit uses Material Design Lite.

What you are looking for, is the style guide / reference of Material Design Lite:

- **Components:** https://getmdl.io/components/index.html
- **Styles:** https://getmdl.io/styles/index.html

**EDIT:** Looks like Material Design Lite is deprecated and being replaced by [Material Design Components](https://material.io/components/). See [Why was material design lite(MDL) deprecated with MDC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769959/why-was-material-design-litemdl-deprecated-with-mdc)